# Popup for each markers with a click

Tags: popup, openlayers, google-maps-markers

I have a series of markers that are placed on the map based on the coordinates stored in a *.js

I was able to add a popup for each marker (as shown in the figure) but it is not exactly what I wanted.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/108179246/Cattura.JPG

I'm trying to insert for each marker a popup that opens only when I click on the respective marker.
This is the code that I've used so far.

```
function showConsideredSamplingPoints() {
        var consideredMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Considered  samplings (" + consideredPoints.length + ")");

        var lonLat = null;
        for (var i = 0, len = consideredPoints.length; i < len; i++) {
            lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(consideredPoints[i].lon, consideredPoints[i].lat)
                .transform(
                    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                    osmmap.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                  );
            var marker= new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat);
            consideredMarkers.addMarker(marker, iconRed.clone());   
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(i,
                         lonLat,
                         new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200),
                         "example popup"+osmmap.popups.length,
                         null, true);
            popup.autoSize = true;

            marker.events.register("click", marker, function(e){    
            osmmap.popups[i].show();
            });

            osmmap.addPopup(popup);               
        }

        osmmap.addLayer(consideredMarkers);}
```

as you can see I tried to insert an event for each marker but not work. Why? What is the error?

SOLUTION: thanks to my friend, I found the solution. there was an error in the declaration of the event. Carry the code correctly and completely.

```
var consideredMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Considered samplings (" +  consideredPoints.length + ")")
    , marker = []
    , lonLat = null
    , len
    , i
    , num
    , osmid
    , popup;

  for (i = 0, len = consideredPoints.length; i < len; i++) {
    lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(consideredPoints[i].lon, consideredPoints[i].lat).transform(
      new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
      osmmap.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    );

    num = consideredPoints[i].num;
    osmid = consideredPoints[i].osmid;
    marker[i] = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat);

    consideredMarkers.addMarker(marker[i], iconRed.clone());

    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
      i, //id
      lonLat, // lonlat
      new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200), // size
      "Point:" + num + " OsmId:" + osmid + "<---", // content
      null, // anchor
      true  // close
    );

    popup.autoSize = true;  // initial setting
    popup.hide();  // hide this popup!

    osmmap.addPopup(popup);  // add to the osmmap popup list

    marker[i].events.register("click", popup, function () {  // add click event
      this.toggle();  // show or hide
    });
  }

  osmmap.addLayer(consideredMarkers);



    }
```

Comment: What exactly did not work?

Comment: Ops, sorry. When I click on a marker the popup does not work!

Comment: You should answer your own question as an answer, not in the question.. @Robert